# Row not creating in SQLite and retrieving AUTOINCREMENT value - Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, auto-increment

Hope this is allowed - I have 2 unrelated questions.

1. This is the main question.  For some reason, my last row in my db is not being created.  I am getting a SQLiteException.  LogCat and code is below.  Error line of code has been commented in.
2. Is there a way to get the value of the AUTOINCREMENT column?  I am having trouble accessing it using this `Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + PERCENTAGE + " FROM " + TABLE + " WHERE " + RANK + " = " + rank, null);` where `RANK` is the AUTOINCREMENT column title.  This cursor always returns 0.

DatabaseHelper.java

```
// Table columns names. 
private static final String RANK = "_id"; 
private static final String SCORE = "score"; 
private static final String PERCENTAGE = "percentage";
private static final String SUM = "sum";

//Check if new record makes the top 10.
public boolean check(long score, int percentage, long sum) {
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + SUM + " FROM " + TABLE, null);  //Line 82
    int z = c.getCount();
    c.moveToLast();
    int x = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(SUM));
    long y = calculateSum(score, percentage);
    if(z != 10) {
        insert(score, percentage, sum);
        return true;
    } else {
        if(y > x) {
            delete(10);
            insert(score, percentage, sum);
            sort();
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

//Insert new record.
public long insert(long score, int percentage, long sum) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(SCORE, score);
    values.put(PERCENTAGE, percentage);
    values.put(SUM, sum);

    return db.insert(TABLE, null, values);
}

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE + " ("
            + RANK + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + SCORE + " LONG,"
            + PERCENTAGE + " INTEGER,"
            + SUM + " LONG"
            + ");");
}
```

LogCat output

```
01-04 02:00:24.635: E/AndroidRuntime(6224): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-04 02:00:24.635: E/AndroidRuntime(6224): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.Results}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: sum (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT sum FROM HighscoresList
01-04 02:00:24.635: E/AndroidRuntime(6224):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
01-04 02:00:24.635: E/AndroidRuntime(6224):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
01-04 02:00:24.635: E/AndroidRuntime(6224):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-04 02:00:24.635: E/AndroidRuntime(6224):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
01-04 02:00:24.635: E/AndroidRuntime(6224):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-04 02:00:24.635: E/AndroidRuntime(6224):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-04 02:00:24.635: E/AndroidRuntime(6224):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-04 02:00:24.635: E/AndroidRuntime(6224):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-04 02:00:24.635: E/AndroidRuntime(6224):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-04 02:00:24.635: E/AndroidRuntime(6224):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-04 02:00:24.635: E/AndroidRuntime(6224):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-04 02:00:24.635: E/AndroidRuntime(6224):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-04 02:00:24.635: E/AndroidRuntime(6224): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: sum (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT sum FROM HighscoresList
01-04 02:00:24.635: E/AndroidRuntime(6224):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
01-04 02:00:24.635: E/AndroidRuntime(6224):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
01-04 02:00:24.635: E/AndroidRuntime(6224):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
01-04 02:00:24.635: E/AndroidRuntime(6224):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
01-04 02:00:24.635: E/AndroidRuntime(6224):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
01-04 02:00:24.635: E/AndroidRuntime(6224):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
01-04 02:00:24.635: E/AndroidRuntime(6224):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
01-04 02:00:24.635: E/AndroidRuntime(6224):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
01-04 02:00:24.635: E/AndroidRuntime(6224):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1253)
01-04 02:00:24.635: E/AndroidRuntime(6224):     at com.example.test.DatabaseHelper.check(DatabaseHelper.java:82)
01-04 02:00:24.635: E/AndroidRuntime(6224):     at com.example.test.Results.showResults(Results.java:111)
01-04 02:00:24.635: E/AndroidRuntime(6224):     at com.example.test.Results.onCreate(Results.java:60)
01-04 02:00:24.635: E/AndroidRuntime(6224):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
01-04 02:00:24.635: E/AndroidRuntime(6224):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
01-04 02:00:24.635: E/AndroidRuntime(6224):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
01-04 02:00:24.635: E/AndroidRuntime(6224):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is something wrong with creating the table. The stacktrace shows an error while retrieving values from Your "sum" column. This error means, that there is no column called "sum". Is it possible that You are trying to get values before this table is created?
2. You could retrieve the datas with a for loop:

   ```
   for(int i=0;i<z;i++){

   int ID = yourCursor.getInt(0);

   if(ID==YOUR_NEEDED_ID){

     int percantage = yourCursor.getInt(2);
      break; //if you got what you want, cursor could be stopped
    }

    yourCursor.moveToNext();

   }
   ```

### EDIT

to upgrade db use

```
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int arg1, int arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        onCreate(db);
    }
```

Comment: Actually, I atlered my db and added a new column after it was already created.  Am I supposed to use my ````onUpgrade()```` in some way after altering my db?  My ````onUpgrade()```` is empty right now.  Should something be in it?

Comment: see my edit. I got a table and this worked good. If You want to upgrade a table/database, You have to recreate it.